# В ногах и в головах.

Tags: грамотная-речь

У А. Битова читаю: "Я сплю на крыше. Поперёк ущелья. В ногах хребет и в головах хребет". Интересно, почему принято говорить в подобных случях "в головах": ведь голова-то одна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В головах** значит 'в изголовье', т.е. в той части постели, где находится голова. (Т.Ф. Ефремова. Новый словарь русского языка. Толково-словообразовательный)

Comment: ... где находится голова (ед. ч.). Почему же "в головах" во множественном?Какова этимология?

Comment: В деревенских избах кроватей было немного (при многочисленных семьях). Спали на лавках, на полатях, на печи. Кровать на одного - роскошь. Обычно кровать - родительская. Вряд ли они спали "валетом" :-)) Естественнее, конечно, головАМИ ложиться к изголовью. Вы не находите? ))

Comment: Нахожу;)))

Answer (score 0):

В головах (В ГОЛОВАХ сидеть, висеть, быть и т. п)— нареч. обстоят. места разг. В той части постели, куда ложатся головой. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова.
2000.   "Мать сидела в головах милых сыновей своих, ни на минуту не сводила с них глаз и не думала о сне" (Гоголь. Тарас Бульба).Фраза "в голове"  звучала бы крайне неожиданно.